# IPTV Link loop ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, vlc

So I want to record a transport stream it's not a m3u
http://flamingzebra.xyz/2728.ts
I tried to record it in vlc it doesn't work The live stream is in fragments so I have to loop it.

Can this be done with ffmpeg, and is there a way I can just download the fragments.

Note that is not a link

Comment: Need to know the protocol of the stream.

Comment: I think the protocol is http